# Multiple declarations together in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am not familiar with jQuery so very much possible that I am overlooking something simple.

Is there a way to define these objects together, instead of 3 different instances?

```
      $( "#accordion") .accordion({
          active: false,
          collapsible: true,
          icons: icons,
          autoHeight: false,
          heightStyle: "content"
      });

      $( "#accordion_fulfillment") .accordion({
          active: false,
          collapsible: true,
          icons: icons,
          autoHeight: false,
          heightStyle: "content"
      });

      $( "#accordion_warehouse") .accordion({
          active: false,
          collapsible: true,
          icons: icons,
          autoHeight: false,
          heightStyle: "content"
      });
```

I have tried doing the obvious but it's not working $( "#accordion", "#accordion_fulfillment", "#accordion_warehouse") .accordion({....})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close!

```
$( "#accordion, #accordion_fulfillment, #accordion_warehouse") .accordion({....})
```

Comment: Care to help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218364/identify-the-dom-element-selector-and-tab-automatically

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way using `attribute` selectors:

```
$( "[id^='accordion']") .accordion({ // <----this selects all ids which starts 
      active: false,                 //      with accordion
      collapsible: true,
      icons: icons,
      autoHeight: false,
      heightStyle: "content"
  });
```

Read more here [**jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: If interested in something much tougher - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218364/identify-the-dom-element-selector-and-tab-automatically